# Check item count before for-each in XSLT / Umbraco

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I am working with XSLT files in an Umbraco solution.

I want the entire ul tag to disappear if there is no elements to be shown:

```
<ul>
  <xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($source)/child::* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
    <li>
      <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}" class="menuitem">
        <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
      </a>
    </li>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

How can I make a IF statement that skips the entire codeblock if the foreach loop has no items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the nodes you are going to select in a variable first, and then wrapping the output of a **ul** element in an xsl:if where you test the number of nodes.

Something like this should do:

```
<xsl:variable name="children" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($source)/child::* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']" />
<xsl:if test="count($children) > 0">
   <ul>
     <xsl:for-each select="$children">
       <li>
         <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}" class="menuitem">
           <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
         </a>
       </li>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </ul>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I insert your code, Umbraco complains that another LI element is unclosed: "The 'xsl:variable' start tag on line 64 position 7 does not match the end tag of 'li'. Line 77, position 5." Maybe I could use Razor templates instead?

Comment: My mistake. The xsl:variable tag was not closed in my sample. I have fixed this if you want to try again.